# given incrementing ID values and a created date, create a SQL statement to find if any of the dates are out of step with the ID in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table like below:
created is a TIMESTAMP(6), and ID is NUMBER(20,0)

```
| ID | CREATED                    | ...
| 1  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.611000 | ...
| 2  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.680000 | ...
```

Determine all the rows where `CREATED` dates are out of step with the incrementing ID values.
If the values are ordered by ID, is any `CREATED` < the previous CREATED value.

I have attempted it, and found that my version is cartesioning horribly, and not returning results. I am sure I am missing some efficiencies in the query.

As output I need the ID/CREATED of the rows that are out of step.

Comment: what you want as an output please provide that one in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you need analytic function `lead()` for comparison of next level row with current and if it greater than the current then it will come to your output

```
with cte as
(
select id,CREATED,lead(CREATED) over(order by id) as NR
from t
) select id,created from cte where CREATED>NR
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) you can generate order numbers by `ID` and `CREATED` and then match them to each other:

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over(order by id) as id_order,
               row_number() over(order by created, id) as created_order
          from t)
 where id_order <> created_order
```

For `created_order` I sort by both `created` and `id` just in case if `created` contains duplicated values.

This query will return all of the affected rows. For example, for a data like this:

```
| ID | CREATED                    | ...
| 1  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.611000 | ...
| 2  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.680000 | ...
| 3  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.612000 | ...
| 4  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.613000 | ...
| 5  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.681000 | ...
| 6  | 2019-11-01 14:19:28.681000 | ...
```

the query will return rows 2, 3 and 4.